# Google Chrome: Separate taskbar windows?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, taskbar

Recently I've been having a problem with my taskbar and haven't been able to find a response/fix or at least I'm unsure in how to word it properly... but here goes.

I have 2 monitors so most of the time I'm running 2 instances of Google Chrome.
My taskbar is set to never combine which is exactly how I want it. Sounds good right?

Lately however, I've noticed something that's beginning to tick me off, here's my problem:
When both instances are open, they are stuck together.
I try to move one of the instances along the taskbar and it just moves both of them, I can't stick (for example) paint between the two instances. Whenever I drag paint to the middle of the two Google Chrome tabs on the taskbar, it just flicks to the left or the right of them and simply refuses to let any instance between them.

Now it probably sounds like a silly thing to complain about but it's actually rather annoying.
How do I stop them both being dragged? How do I 'unstick' them?

(Congratulations to anyone who can actually understand what I mean by all this... I'm not the best with descriptions)

Comment: you can check here http://superuser.com/questions/633052/how-to-prevent-google-chrome-from-creating-seprate-taskbar-icon-for-each-profile but it doesnt look like there is a solid solution to this

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding another profile i Chrome. Right click on your name profile and choose manage People, Add another profile and choose an icon, no need for another email address, you can have more than a profile.
Problem solved now you've a separate Icon on your taskbar.

[image]